# How would I make every other thing in a list in a different variable list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying to make it so that every even thing in a list goes to one variable, and every odd one goes to another. For example, let's say `x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. How would I make `y = ["a", "c"]` and `z = ["b", "d"]`?

I have not made any script with this yet, but I will in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean:

```
>>> y, z = x[::2], x[1::2]
>>> y
['a', 'c']
>>> z
['b', 'd']
>>>
```

Comment: I love symmetry and I'd write `y, z = x[0::2], x[1::2]` instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
x=['a','b','c','d']

y[:]=x[::2]  #start from 0 index value : till the end of list : step (every second element)
z[:]=x[1::2] #start from 1 index value : till the end of list : step (every second element)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [i for i in x if x.index(i)%2==0]
b = [i for i in x if x.index(i)%2!=0]
```

Comment: `index` returns the index of the first occurrence, this will only work for unique lists (which OP never mentioned his are).